# First answer reviews - feedback for link-only answers

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, first-answers

Link-only answers are usually of poor quality and the link should be just a supporting information, while the information should be provided within the answer itself. Such answers are often flagged as [VLQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420), and then deleted. The possible information in first answer queue is that

- the answer is unclear

  > As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
- the answer needs supporting information

  > Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
- custom

It is clear that if you provide a link with a valid solution, this is neither unclear, nor needs more citations or documentation. It simply needs to be described within the body of the answer as there is a high possibility that the link will become dead one day.

This is a quite common issue and entering a custom comment each time wastes your time. I am thus requesting to add a standard auto-comment for this situation, for example:

- The answer is link only

  > While the link can lead to a correct solution, link-only answers with minimum explanation can become unhelpful in case the linked content changes after a time. Please [edit] the answer and add supporting information, such as a code or further explanation.

This is just an example that came up in my mind, and maybe there is a better idea for a standard text. However, I am sure that it is better to give new users a chance to understand what is incorrect in this case instead of simply removing the answer.

Yes, I know that this is captured in the [LQP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) queue as

- This is a link-only answer (and not spam)

  > “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Maybe it could be merged and this auto-comment could be added for reply-and-flag into the first answer queue? Possibly there can be some problems I can't think of right now and this idea is not good. Let's discuss :)

Comment: I see this as a microcosm of a bigger issue: The feedback options available in _First Answers_ aren’t aligned with the range of common problems we see with first answers, many of which are supported in _Low Quality Answers_. Ideally, this would work similar to _Late Answers_, which duplicates the delete reasons from _LQA_. **@Ryan-M [suggested this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/724530)** when the new queues were released, but it got overlooked relative to the larger bug it was suggested in response to. (At the time, there was no “I’m done” option when you flagged a post.)

Comment: In addition to **Link-Only Answers**, the two I’d really like to see: **Code-Only Answers** and **Answers on Established Questions**. Neither are _necessarily_ a reason to delete, but they’re both an opportunity for feedback, and are really common in the queues.

Comment: What do you mean by "answers on established questions?"  Are you talking about late answers on questions that already have good answers?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Yes, exactly. In those cases, if there an obvious duplicate, I’ll flag it. But otherwise, I’ll leave a comment like, “There are **thirty-eight** existing answers to this question, including a top-rated answer with **211 upvotes**. Are you _sure_ your answer hasn't already been provided? If not, why might someone prefer your approach over the existing approaches proposed? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities? Are there scenarios where your approach is better suited? Explanations are always useful, but are especially important here.”

Comment: @JeremyCaney I usually use one of the auto-comments that is relevant for code-only, such answers should be just described further so "needs supporting information" is usually enough. The second problem might be interesting for further discussion, yes. Also multiple times I flag with custom flag new answers to old questions as they tend to  be duplicates, rephrasing, no new info, merge of multiple answers, etc., which is unneeded. In this case I usually write a specific feedback for a specific answer.

Answer (score 7):

I've started using a custom reason for link-only answers:

> `I flagged this for [deletion](/help/deleted-answers) because it consists almost entirely of a link. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is [useful without it](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259): add context around the link so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part in case the linked page is unavailable. If you [edit] this answer to add more once it is deleted, please flag it for moderator attention so that it can be un-deleted.`

The ideal reason should:

- Succinctly and directly explain the problem in the first sentence without apology.
- Briefly explain why link-only answers are not good.
- Link to a full explanation.
- Give actionable feedback about how the answer should be improved.

It would be nice if the default reasons could be improved, but I'm not holding my breath.   Stack Exchange seems to want to try to keep a small number of reasons even if more specific reasons would be appropriate for more specific situations.

Self promotion:   I wrote a script to easily add custom reasons for comments, closing, and flags.  This custom text is one of the default pre-canned comments included: https://github.com/stephenostermiller/stack-exchange-comment-templates

Comment: I know many users do so, but I was thinking that there could also be standardized auto-comments for such a common situation. I don't see a reason why there shouldn't be.