# Should we add option "Use complete sentences" to First Answers queue?

Tags: discussion, grammatical-correction, first-answers, spelling

I just did 10 reviews of the First Answers queue. Out of them, 3 were using non-capitalized sentences and lacked punctuation. This seems to be endemic.

Sometimes I edit, sometimes I comment. I would like a standard community bot comment for that. I generally write something along those lines:

> Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the time to edit your answers to use proper sentences, with punctuation and capitalization. This will make them more readable for your peers. Thank you!

*Side-note:* I know there are not only native English speakers here (I am not, for instance), and am willing to forgive on the wording of the sentences. However, putting a dot and a capital helps so much to read, compared to free-flow lines of words, especially when the wording is not best chosen! I'm not sure that editing such basic things for them helps them learn appropriately.

---

Since the choice of the sentence has a few comments below, here is a version based on the existing wording of the two other available canned comments:

> As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to
> correct punctuation, spelling and grammar. This will help others understand how this addresses the question
> asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers
> [in the help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers).

Comment: Re *"not only native English speakers"*: They are perfectly capable of doing it. They just can't be bothered. They have the minimum-effort attitude. Thus the comments are futile.

Comment: Re my first comment: I have only ever seen [one instance](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17796151/1) where a comment worked (the comment is now deleted). Though there is ***definitely*** some [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias).

Comment: I am all for it. At least we can say: *"We tried."* Perhaps a conversion rate of 1% is better than nothing.

Comment: "*But the point is : should we add that option?*" => Yes, but not only for 'First Answers Queue', but for 'First Questions Queue' also, ... and "everywhere" actually...!

Comment: Suggested wording: "*Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the time to edit your answer to use proper sentences, with punctuation and capitalization. and correct spelling and grammar. This will make it more readable for other users. Thank you!*" // You had a Typo also in "welcome **so** Stack Overflow...*"

Comment: Shouldn't we also include typo's, obvious spelling mistakes and the use of chat language in these comments? I think that the problem is a lot bigger than just punctuation.

Comment: Partly, this happens because they don't understand that Stack Exchange sites are Q&A repositories, [not forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/334566). Since it's their first answer, they deserve to be informed about our policy. But if they persist in posting poorly formatted answers, there's a nice big ▼ button to mark the answer as Not Useful.

Comment: @The_spider - yes, the *text-speak* is most irritating: Today I saw "shud" used for "should", which sent shivers down my spine.

Comment: Maybe add something like "and use blank lines to form paragraphs"... I find walls of text harder to read than an occasional typo.

Comment: @Robert: The two other canned answers link to "[in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)". We could make the statement shorter, and link to a similar page such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers). Then make sure that the page we link to includes all of what we want to be done, like the one you just suggested...

Comment: Edited question, let me know if there is a better place where "in the help center" should lead for this particular case. I think I found a [reasonably good meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers), but it would be better if it was really linking to something in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/)!

Comment: Not everyone agrees that full sentences should be used BTW: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/311903#311903

Comment: If a post is understandable, then we really shouldn't care. Feel free to edit to improve phrasing/grammar/spelling but we shouldn't punish people for this.

Comment: @DavidG I disagree. You should write any question here of the same quality as the language you would use in a business e-mail. Doing otherwise will be considered rude and will make yourself and the company you work for look like a bunch of clowns. It is not the purpose of SO to educate children (in adult bodies) about common decency and how to interact with other humans. That's a required prerequisite before coming here. Teaching it is the job of parents and daycare/elementary school teachers. It is not a job for the professional or enthusiast programmers using this site.

Comment: @Rubén Why did you remove the feature request tag? If this isn't a feature request then I don't know what is...

Comment: @Lundin Because it doesn't look as a feature request. Ref. [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/1595451)

Comment: @DavidG I see these comments more as tips than as a punishment... or at least I hope that this is how they are received! In that regard I prefer my original "welcome / thank you" message than the formal one I have added in the edit. However, the formal one is more uniform with the existing canned comments.

Comment: @Rubén As my first meta post, I would say it was a reasonable attempt at a feature request. Thanks to your link I found the Data Explorer. However, I could not get a clear number of comments about use of language, since programming languages use the same terminology, and comments are mixed between English and code ([result](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1688136/comments-about-quality-of-english)). [Querying for edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1688147/edits-about-quality-of-english) is more accurate but slightly off-topic.

Comment: JM Lord: Even on Meta comments should not be used to have extended discussions and questions that already got good answers should not have big changes (perhaps the only exception are posts about tags that are converted into burnination requests). If you are looking for help on using SEDE for an specific case that have not already asked, please post a new question. P.S. Please avoid the use of "Edit", "update" as content separator, instead add a more descriptive section title.

Comment: Text quality can be easily improved by flagging grammar issues up-front in the editor while the text is being written.  Most spelling and grammatical errors can be fixed using a tool such as [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com).  This tool is useful even if you can write well (*try it yourself for a week to see this*).  Integrating such technology into the editors reduces the need or desire to flag posts for quality, as proposed here.  If desired, both improved editors and improved post-publishing correction systems can be adopted.

Comment: *"I'm not sure that editing such basic things for them helps them learn appropriately."* - you're not here to teach people things. Not a tutoring site, not a school. What I find bad is that people put up barriers for themselves. "I am not going to edit because the other person might not learn from it". Great. There goes the editing process down the tubes.

Answer (score 16):

Previous related [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s

- [First answer reviews - feedback for link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413510/1595451)
- [Formatting feedback for First Answers review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415828/1595451)

---

AFAIK the comments shown in the First Answers / Questions queue can't be customized per-site (meaning that SO mods can't add a new canned comment to the review queues), but recently the Staging Ground team requested suggestions for canned comments, a bit later they made a follow-up post: [Staging Ground Workflow: Canned Comments - Revised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421896/1595451)

On the follow-up post, there are a list of canned comments, one of them mentions formatting, spelling and grammar:

> **Proofread for minor edits** : Your question is almost ready to post! Please proofread and edit it to improve the formatting and correct any spelling or grammar mistakes.

Related

- [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/1595451)
- [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291362/1595451)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links. The formulation above is intended at questions, rather than  answers. I just went through the posts and to my understanding, Staging Ground is indeed for questions. Without having to add a new feature like staging ground, I still feel that a canned comment should be added to the existing ones, especially that writing good sentences applies to all StackExchange websites for sure. The fact that it "can't be customized per-site" is not a barrier in my opinion, but I understand it requires a wider consensus.

Answer (score 11):

In my experience it's the non-native English speakers (typers?) like yourself who make the most effort to write good English. As a native English speaker who cares about quality and accuracy and readability, I greatly appreciate that.

But this is a website about programming, not English. And if a programming answer is correct and sufficiently understandable even with lacking spelling and/or grammar, I don't see it as the end of the world. I'd rather get that useful answer on the site where a curator can eventually panel-beat it into shape, as opposed to posting a comment that will either be ignored, or could lead to a user interpreting it negatively and removing their contribution.

In short, while I'm not **opposed** to the idea of a new canned comment or option in the review queue (although the likelihood of the latter happening in a reasonable timeframe is... *poor*), I don't see particular value in adding it.

Comment: @Lundin Remember that we are talking about **answers** here, not questions. For me, the bar for spelling and grammar is considerably lower for answers because code should be the majority of said answer; the English around it should be generally superfluous and as such can probably be whacked into shape at a later date by a curator, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Lundin Further, I've worked with more than one developer whose command of typed English was extremely poor, but ability to understand and explain code was phenomenal. For of them, and many people in general, written comms simply aren't something they care to put much effort into; that is indeed laziness, but it's a laziness generally born out of having different priorities, and that's not inherently disrespectful, just different.

Comment: Or perhaps instead of "not inherently disrespectful", I should say "not *intentionally* disrespectful". Those who make the effort to use good spelling and grammar are rightfully proud of their efforts to Do It Right, and often misinterpret the actions of others unwilling to make that same effort, as purposefully disrespectful (I have been personally guilty of this). Neither group is wrong, nor right.

Answer (score 1):

If a question or answer is not at all comprehendable, mark it as such.  If you can read it but doesn't have correct grammar and punctuation, that's kinda on you.  If it really bothers you, fix it and if not, move on.

I've noticed that highly rated/useful questions and answers get re-written (repeatedly) anyway, so the only thing marking with a tag like this does is make someone else feel bad--they are unlikely to be able to fix it anyway. It really doesn't do anyone any good (Except possibly the person who gets to feel superior by marking it).

I guess I'd ask, given that popular questions and answers end up getting re-written repeatedly regardless of their original grammar--what's the goal of this change?  You're not going to get better content, just a higher bar to entry and more frusterated new users thinking that the site doesn't want their content.